# NGINX: SETTING DELAY TIME IN BURST

Tags: nginx

As per my understanding, in limit_req in nginx, we set the limit as max req/sec. On breaching that limit, further requests are put in the burst queue and delivered/executed at a delay. If burst is also breached, user get 503 error.( If delay is not required then noday can be set )

What I am not able to find is setting the delay time for the requests in burst queue.

i. e. : if burst is set at 30, then, can i set the delay time between two requests which are in burst queue.

Answer (score 1):

The rate determines how fast requests are processed.  If you set the rate to 10r/s, that means 1 request will get processed every 0.1 seconds.

If you get 5 requests all at once, it doesn't mean that they'll all go through because there're less than 10 requests.  They'll get queued up (up to your burst size), and get processed sequentially, every 0.1 seconds.

So you effectively set your delay time between requests with your rate.

If you don't want things getting delayed, then use the nodelay parameter.

For more details on exactly how this works, see https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/